# Succinct data structures survey?

Tags: ds.data-structures, lower-bounds

[Fischer's paper this month](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0395) reminded me how little I know about the art of succinct data structures, and algorithms to use them.

For those that don't know about succinct data structures:

> Given a combinatorial structure, with
>   a(n) distinct configurations, and a
>   known "useful" representation $R(n)$.
>   Is there a "succinct" data structure
>   that takes storage of around
>   $\lg(a(n))$ bits yet lets us perform
>   operations as fast as we can with the
>   normal representation $R$?

The top ones I am interested in if anyone would like to entertain a discussion

1. Suffix Arrays. They are a subset of all permutations.
2. Ordered Trees. They are a subset of all binary "parenthesis" strings (the matched variety).
3. All nearest smaller values, as in the paper ([1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0395)). Not only can you compress in both dimensions; the allowable "smaller value" arrays in one direction are a small subset of lists $\{0,...,n-1\}^n$ , and thus you need to store less than $n \lg(n)$ bits.

Answer (score 7):

Also check out the [thesis of Ankur Gupta](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.9944&rep=rep1&type=pdf), with emphasis on compressible data.

Answer (score 6):

If to speak about succit suffix data structures, this one by Navarro and Mäkinen is really good: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1216370.1216372

Answer (score 3):

There is now a book on the subject: Compact Data Structures: A Practical Approach, by Gonzalo Navarro. https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3092586